# Attempting to Fix Makefile of an 80's Source Code

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to run the makefile from the source code of Chris Crawford's *Balance of Power 1990* using GNU-make. Quite honestly, I have no experience with makefiles nor do I have any idea what I'm doing. The makefile looks like this:

```
GlobDebug=FALSE
"{BOPO}"BOPSRace1 ﾄ "{BOPO}"BOP2.code "{BOPS}"NewResrc.r
    rez "{BOPS}"NewResrc.r -o "DataFrame:BOP2_ﾄ:BOP2"

"{BOPO}"BOP2.code ﾄ "{BOPO}"Globals.p.o ｶ
                    "{BOPO}"AsmCode.a.o ｶ
                    "{BOPO}"Init.p.o ｶ
                    "{BOPO}"Titles.p.o ｶ
                    "{BOPO}"Background.p.o ｶ
                    "{BOPO}"StdRoutines.p.o ｶ
                    "{BOPO}"History.p.o ｶ
                    "{BOPO}"PlanMove.p.o ｶ
                    "{BOPO}"CrisisU.p.o ｶ
                    "{BOPO}"Main.p.o
    link "{Libraries}"Interface.o ｶ
         "{Libraries}"Runtime.o ｶ
         "{PLibraries}"Paslib.o ｶ
         "{BOPO}"Globals.p.o ｶ
         "{BOPO}"AsmCode.a.o ｶ
         "{BOPO}"Init.p.o ｶ
         "{BOPO}"Titles.p.o ｶ
         "{BOPO}"Background.p.o ｶ
         "{BOPO}"StdRoutines.p.o ｶ
         "{BOPO}"History.p.o ｶ
         "{BOPO}"PlanMove.p.o ｶ
         "{BOPO}"CrisisU.p.o ｶ
         "{BOPO}"Main.p.o ｶ
         -o "{BOPO}"BOP2.code

"{BOPO}"AsmCode.a.o ﾄ "{BOPS}"AsmCode.a      
    Asm -o "{BOPO}" "{BOPS}"AsmCode.a       

"{BOPO}"Globals.p.o ﾄ "{BOPS}"Globals.p      
    Pascal -d DebugFlg={GlobDebug} -o "{BOPO}" "{BOPS}"Globals.p

"{BOPO}"Init.p.o ﾄ "{BOPS}"Init.p "{BOPS}"Globals.p          
    Pascal -d DebugFlg={GlobDebug} -o "{BOPO}" "{BOPS}"Init.p

"{BOPO}"Titles.p.o ﾄ "{BOPS}"Titles.p "{BOPS}"Globals.p          
    Pascal -d DebugFlg={GlobDebug} -o "{BOPO}" "{BOPS}"Titles.p

"{BOPO}"Background.p.o ﾄ "{BOPS}"Background.p "{BOPS}"Globals.p          
    Pascal -d DebugFlg={GlobDebug} -o "{BOPO}" "{BOPS}"Background.p

"{BOPO}"StdRoutines.p.o ﾄ "{BOPS}"StdRoutines.p "{BOPS}"Globals.p            
    Pascal -d DebugFlg={GlobDebug} -o "{BOPO}" "{BOPS}"StdRoutines.p

"{BOPO}"History.p.o ﾄ "{BOPS}"History.p "{BOPS}"Globals.p            
    Pascal -d DebugFlg={GlobDebug} -o "{BOPO}" "{BOPS}"History.p

"{BOPO}"PlanMove.p.o ﾄ "{BOPS}"PlanMove.p "{BOPS}"Globals.p          
    Pascal -d DebugFlg={GlobDebug} -o "{BOPO}" "{BOPS}"PlanMove.p

"{BOPO}"CrisisU.p.o ﾄ "{BOPS}"CrisisU.p "{BOPS}"Globals.p            
    Pascal -d DebugFlg={GlobDebug} -o "{BOPO}" "{BOPS}"CrisisU.p

"{BOPO}"Main.p.o ﾄ "{BOPS}"Main.p "{BOPS}"Globals.p 
    Pascal -d DebugFlg={GlobDebug} -o "{BOPO}" "{BOPS}"Main.p
```

Even as a total makefile-noob I can tell that there are some serious encoding errors (ﾄ and ｶ, which showed up as umlaut-A and ¶ in notepad++).

**What I Tried**

I kept getting the "no target specified" error, so I moved the "GlobDebug=False" from the top.

Then I got the "target pattern contains no %" error.

I assumed the (ﾄ) was supposed to be (:), and after replacing them it yielded the "multiple target patterns" error.

At this point I am clueless.

**Questions**

How should these (ﾄ) and (ｶ) be fixed? Are there any other obvious problems with this makefile?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ﾄ` should be `:` and the `ｶ` should be `\` and **last** character of the line. Then , you will have to check that the first character of the lines of the recipes is a tab, not spaces. Example in:

```
"{BOPO}"BOPSRace1 : "{BOPO}"BOP2.code "{BOPS}"NewResrc.r
    rez "{BOPS}"NewResrc.r -o "DataFrame:BOP2_ﾄ:BOP2"
```

the recipe is the second line and it **must** start with a tab.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, I'm still getting the "multiple target patterns" error on the 1st line   "{BOPO}"BOPSRace1 : "{BOPO}"BOP2.code "{BOPS}"NewResrc.r

Comment: @PopaPett: What is the exact error message? Do you know what the variable `BOPO` contains?

Comment: The error message is "Makefile:1: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop." (This is after moving the GlobalDebug thing down.) I really have no idea what BOPO and BOPS is, nor how that's supposed to work. BTW the source code is the first file in [here.](http://www.erasmatazz.com/library/source-code/index.html)

Comment: @PopaPett: I think the problem is there, but I really don't know how this variable is supposed to work. I suggest you temporarily add a new rule to the top of your makefile: `null:[CR]{TAB]@echo the variable contains "{BOPO}"` and see what it gives you.

Comment: @Beta Thanks for your advice, but I'm still getting the same error.   Makefile:1: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

Comment: The `"{BOPO}"`, `"{BOPS}"` and `{GlobDebug}` should probably also be replaced by `$(BOPO)`, `$(BOPS)` and `$(GlobDebug)`. But it is more difficult to say.

Comment: I had a quick look at the original zip archive and I think your main problem is not how to fix this makefile. It is to discover the encoding of the files and convert them all in, e.g., UTF-8: even if you fix this makefile manually, you will get zillions of errors when compiling and you will have to fix all the other files by hand.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Aha! _Make_ wasn't working because the files were in **Macintosh** format!  Sorry to bugger you with all these questions, but now that _Make_ is going past line 1 I've gotten this: `Pascal -d DebugFlg=FALSE -o  Globals.p　
make: Pascal: Command not found　
make: *** [Makefile:35: Globals.p.o] Error 127`.

Comment: You thought it would be C++? It is [pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)), an old and nowadays quite rarer programming language. But don't worry, there are several compilers available. gcc is one of them.